# Merging text files in C

Tags: c, file, merge, strcmp

I've been trying to make a function to merge two text files together into a new file which is then sorted alphabetically. If i'm right then the following code should combine the two files into a new file (newcat) but how can I use the strcmp function to "sort" the strings into alphabetical order?

```
    void combine(FILE* cat1, FILE* cat2, FILE* newcat)
    {
       char ch;

    while((ch = fgetc(cat1)) != EOF)
       fputc(ch,newcat);

    while((ch = fgetc(cat2)) != EOF)
       fputc(ch,newcat);

    fclose (cat1);
    fclose (cat2);
    fclose (newcat);
    }
```

Comment: `char ch;` is **oh so very, very very wrong!** Use `int ch;`.

Comment: you'd have to load the new file into memory as an array of lines, then use a sort algorithm on that line, then write out the sorted array. you cannot do any sorting as you're reading both files, as you're just reading them character-by-character.

Comment: "I've been trying" and "If I'm right" makes no sense. If you've been trying, you'd know if the code was right or not, which means you haven't tried it. Please try to figure out your homework yourself first, and then post the code and specific questions about what isn't working the way you expect. If we do the work for you, you won't learn anything except how to copy and paste other people's work. :)

Comment: Is this homework? If it is and you have to use C you'll have to find a simple sorting algorithm. Insert sort is slow, but it takes even less time than a bubble sort.

Answer (score 1):

For each file you can consider each string and then using `strcmp` compare  strings using any sorting algorithm of your choice and place the result on the destination file. That will merge the files in alphabetical order.